# Spring Boot how to authenticate/login with BCrypt

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I'm currently creating an application with Spring Boot and Angular and for that I need an user. I allready created can save the password hashed in the DB. That works fine. But I have no idea, if my current solution is any good. I don't know how to login an user too. Does anyone have any idea how or what I can do?

**UserController**
Here I send my HTTP request. Here I encrypt the password and send an HTTP response.

```
@Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> registerNewUserAccount(@Validated @RequestBody User accountDto) {
        accountDto.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(accountDto.getPassword()));
        if (userService.save(accountDto) == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("E-Mail already exists", HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**UserServiceImpl**
Here I check, if the email allready exists. the findByEmail method is in UserRepository.

```
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public User save(User object) {
        if (userRepository.findByEmail(object.getEmail()) == null) {
            return userRepository.save(object);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**UserService (Interface)**
This is basic.

```
public interface UserService extends CrudService<User, Integer> {
    User save(User object);
    List<User> findAll();
    void deleteById(Integer id);
    User findById(Integer id);
    void delete(User object);
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question requires a tutorial, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/arbiss1/SpringBootJpa-and-Security/tree/main/src/main/java/net/codejava

Here's my repo for spring security implementation . Follow it step by step and you will get what you want . Your question needs a lot of explanation .